# HiveQL thru Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hiveql

I tried to run a simple Hive query using Spark thru Intellij.

build.sbt

```
name := "products"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "2.2.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "2.2.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.2.1"
```

My program:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SaveMode, SparkSession}
import java.io.File

object hiveextract {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit={
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("hiveextract")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val warehouseLocation = new File("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse").getAbsolutePath
    //val hc = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
    val hc = SparkSession.builder().appName( "SparkSessionZipsExample").config( "spark.sql.warehouse.dir" , warehouseLocation).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    import hc.implicits._
    import hc.sql

    hc.sql("select * from retail.temperatur").show()

  }
}
```

I am getting the below error. Is there any version mismatch? How can I resolve this issue?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate SparkSession with Hive support because Hive classes are not found.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.enableHiveSupport(SparkSession.scala:854)
    at hiveextract$.main(hiveextract.scala:13)
    at hiveextract.main(hiveextract.scala)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with latest version of spark dependenices.

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.3.0"
```